# How to import a jar file into eclipse and use the source code

Tags: eclipse, import

I need to import a jar file that I was given and edit the source code, but I don't know how to import the jar file without just adding it to the library. It includes the source code, and I can open that in notepad++ and copy paste it, but it gives me some errors this way.

Answer (score 0):

Jar files are just zip archives, so you can extract it somewhere and create a new project from this files to open in eclipse. Then you need to compile all this classes to .class files when you done editing them and compress again with the same directory structure using zip archiver.